# Securing Bluetooth LE Messages

Tags: security, encryption, bluetooth, aes, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a requirement to communicate with a custom Bluetooth LE device. The communication needs to be

- Secure (plain text cannot be read)
- Not vulnerable to replay attacks
- Contained within 20 or 22 bytes per message to Bluetooth LE restrictions (or phone API implementation restrictions)

Trusting Bluetooth LE's native encryption alone seems to be a poor choice based on this:

https://github.com/mikeryan/crackle/

So then we come to implementing our own encryption. In a normal client / server communication (TCP for example) with no message size restriction, AES-128 in CBC mode with a pre-shared private key might be a good choice.

However with Bluetooth LE

- There's not enough space to transmit an Initialization Vector with each Characteristic read / write
- It seems error prone to keep track of changing IVs based on the last block of the last message received / transmitted, given multiple Characteristics being broadcast etc.

Have I missed some other way of making Bluetooth LE secure?

Comment: If the packets can be identified (sequence number) then you could use CTR mode encryption and derive the IV from the unique identifier. It's a bit strange that you have both "no package size restriction" and "not enough space to transmit an Initialization Vector" though.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question for clarity. Problem I see with any kind of sequence is that the Bluetooth device is broadcasting Characteristics and it's entirely possible that the client (Phone) might not receive some of those broadcasts, therefore losing track of the sequence.

Comment: Did you look at Man In The Middle protection? LE is designed to be lightweight and the encryption specified by the Sig reflects that.

Comment: from my experience it isn't very feasible trying to implement custom encryption. As Simon said, Bluetooth LE wasn't meant to be highly encrypted/encryptable. Maybe some other approach could work? Although I can't think of any.

Answer (score 0):

...fragment the data to 20 bytes and do multiple write to a BLE characteristic stored in the GATT. You will need to come up with a protocol to reassemble the fragmented data.

To fight the replay attack you can generate, before each new connection, a new challenge request and broadcast it via advertisement. It will be picked up by the central and returned encrypted to the peripheral. Make sure you generate a new challenge for each new connection.

The Bluetooth LE pairing (not including OOB) cannot be trusted from security point. There is a need to encrypt the data at the firmware application level on top of the pairing (using Just Work or better). Implementation of symmetric encryption (AES128 or 256) with challenge request is a good way to start.

Lastly, I would suggest to dig into the BLE OOB (Out-Of-Band) pairing that allows the exchange of a symmetric pairing key between the central and peripheral. That would also be a decent alternative to secure the communication. There are couple of implementation with NFC available.